# xpath expression: find value of element based on other element

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to find the value of the presenter if the value of the title is 'This is a title'

```
<AXFRoot>
    <MAObject type="default" mdclass="PROGRAM">
        <GUID dmname="">ID00001</GUID>
    </MAObject>
    <MVAttribute type="RUNDOWN" index="0" attribute="RUNDOWN" mdclass="PROGRAM" objectid="ID00001">
        <Meta name="TITLE" format="string">This is a title</Meta>
        <Meta name="AIRDATE" format="string">20201001194131</Meta>
        <Meta name="PAGE_NUMBER" format="string">01</Meta>
        <Meta name="PRESENTER" format="string">abcdef</Meta>
        <Meta name="AUDIO_TIME" format="string">0</Meta>
        <Meta name="TOTAL_TIME" format="string">0</Meta>
        <Meta name="ARCHIVE" format="string">0</Meta>
        <Meta name="MOS_TITLE" format="string" />
    </MVAttribute>
    <MVAttribute type="RUNDOWN" index="1" attribute="RUNDOWN" mdclass="PROGRAM" objectid="ID00001">
        <Meta name="TITLE" format="string">This is another title</Meta>
        <Meta name="AIRDATE" format="string">20201001194131</Meta>
        <Meta name="PAGE_NUMBER" format="string">01</Meta>
        <Meta name="PRESENTER" format="string">ghijkl</Meta>
        <Meta name="AUDIO_TIME" format="string">0</Meta>
        <Meta name="TOTAL_TIME" format="string">0</Meta>
        <Meta name="ARCHIVE" format="string">0</Meta>
        <Meta name="MOS_TITLE" format="string" />
    </MVAttribute>
</AXFRoot>
```

So far I got

```
//AXFRoot/MVAttribute[@type='RUNDOWN']/Meta[@name='TITLE' and text()='This is a title']
```

but this only gives me the title element, not the value of the presenter. What do I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
//AXFRoot/MVAttribute[@type='RUNDOWN']
                     /Meta[@name='TITLE' and text()='This is a title']
                     /../Meta[@name='PRESENTER']
```

or

```
//AXFRoot/MVAttribute[@type='RUNDOWN']
                     [Meta[@name='TITLE' and text()='This is a title']]
                     /Meta[@name='PRESENTER']
```

Comment: Thanks! And is there a way to get this working for xpath v1.0? :-s

Comment: This is XPath v1.0 (tested in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) which uses libxml2). Just added indentation for clarity.